# How do I compare two spreadsheets to identify missing line items and add them?

Tags: python-3.x, xlsx

I am trying to compare two .xlsx files. What I am looking to do is basically the following:

Does any cell in column B of file1 exist in column B of file2?
   If yes, continue.
   Else, add the row to file2

The structure of the files is different, so I would need to organize the information being added to file2 to match the format, also, but I think I would be able to do that myself once I know how to do the transfer.

The files are basically a vulnerability export from ACAS and a POA&M. I want to add any existing vulnerabilities from the export that are not already represented on the POA&M.

Comment: Use can [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for this.